# PHP PDO Return single row

Tags: php, pdo

I have database with five projects added by username. When I want to get project by user returns me only one project.

```
      <?php
      require_once("db.php");
      $db = DB();
      $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE username='$username'");
      $query->execute();
      $row = $query->fetch();
      $name = $row['name'];
      $project = $row['project'];
    echo "<p>Project name: $name</p>
          <p>Project: $project</p>
        ?>
```

Comment: Fetch using `while`

Comment: change this ` $row = $query->fetch();` to ` $row = $query->fetchAll();` then loop with `while` or `foreach` loop. Fetch is returns you only 1 result

Comment: btw; you don't need the `prepare/execute`, you can just do `query()`. However, you're not "preparing" anything *per se* yet you should and use a prepared statement. What you have now doesn't qualify as a prepared statement to which you're open to an sql injection.

Comment: RTM on PDO's `fetch()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Damn. So easy... Thank you!

Comment: Plus, if that's your real code `echo "<p>Project name: $name</p>
          <p>Project: $project</p>` is missing a quote and a semi-colon and would throw a parse error.

Comment: I forgot to add them. Now my code is `$sql  = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE username = '$username'"; foreach($db->query($sql) as $row)` Should I be worried about sql injection?